# Spring security with soap

Tags: java, spring

I need to make a SOAP webservice and a web client. I have been trying for several days to implement and configure spring security on the ws to control authentication with a database but without success.

I use spring boot 2.2 with spring security.

I would like the user to authenticate only on certain actions and from a database and not by putting the password in hard.

Could you explain me how works spring security with soap ? I didn't find good and simple explanation.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Start with the in-memory authentication and if it works, continue with the DB integration.

Comment: I suggest to yuo to use Spring OAuth2 for SOAP authentication with spring. Generally WS SOAP are consumed by business applications and they can't handle a login page. Moreover SOAP is stateless while classical authentication is, by nature, stateful

Comment: Thanks. I am going to search about Oauth2 for soap. Do you know a good tutorial or example ?